Feasibility of Applying QAOA to Quantum Chemistry Calculations
Is it possible to apply QAOA (or quantum alternating operator ansatz) to quantum chemistry calculations for NISQ devices? If not, why? If it is possible, why is it not commonly seen?

You mean is it possible to use QAOA instead of the more commonly used VQE for this task?
If yes, is there a reason why you would want to do that?

Yes, that's correct. I don't understand why QAOA isn't used for quantum chemistry calculations. If VQE determines parameters randomly, it can cause issues like barren plateaus. However, QAOA corresponds to adiabatic time evolution and might not need to determine parameters randomly.

I would like to add that QAOA also typically considers a random (or close to it) parameter initialization, at least in its most common variational variant. One could also try to essentially implement Trotterized adiabatic evolution, but I don't think anyone does that. At that point you might just use a Quantum Computer specifically designed for Quantum Annealing, not for gate-based computing.

The reason is simply because VQE, which is mostly used in this domain, and QAOA, which is mostly used in combinatorial optimization, serve different purposes.
The problem VQE solves is:

Being given an Hamiltonian $H$, we are interested in finding the lowest eigenvalue of $H$.

While the problem QAOA solves is:

Being given a problem Hamiltonian $H_p$ and a solution Hamiltonian $H_s$, find a ground state of $H_s$ being given a ground state of $H_p$.

In Quantum Chemistry, the problem we want to solve is VQE's: we're interested in the smallest eigenvalue of $H$, so it's natural to use VQE.
In this case, you could view VQE as a generalized QAOA. If you were to use QAOA for this problem, you would:

Start from a known Hamiltonian $H_p$ and create a ground state out of it
Evolve the state to a ground state $|\psi\rangle$ of $H$
Compute the expectation value $\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$ to obtain an upper-bound of the smallest eigenvalue of $H$
Optimize the angles in step 2 using a classical optimizer and start again.

This workflow is exactly that of VQE. The only difference lies in the ansatz that you use: in QAOA it is determined by $H_p$, $H$ and the number of steps $p$. In VQE, you don't really have a restriction.
Furthermore, the problem is: how do you choose $H_p$? You have to use an Hamiltonian such that you can create an eigenstate of it, but at the same time, ideally, you'd want it to be not too far from $H$ so that $p$ isn't too large. It's quite a restrictive constraint, so it's easier to choose an ansatz that we know performs (for empirical or physical-oriented reasons) well and stick to VQE.

The use of QAOA for quantum chemistry has been discussed in the literature.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.13056
